# How do I make the space before the text disappear without making the space between the texts disappear on every sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I make the space before the text disappear without making the space between the texts disappear  on every sheet ? I've tried to come up with the following code.

```
    Public Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'or change to something like ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100") for a specific range
        rng.Value2 = Trim(rng.Value2)
    Next
End Sub
```

But it's really slow and will only apply to the first sheet out of my 3 sheets. Basically I want to change a cell like "       Total Revenue" into "Total Revenue" and would like to apply my code on all 3 sheets I, B and C. Thank you guys in advance !

[image: Texts I want to change]

Comment: Those extra spaces heavily improve the readability of your page, why do you want to remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Trim Ranges

**Basic**

- Note that this will convert any formulas to values.

```vb
Sub TrimAllWorksheetsBasic()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' or:
    'Set wb = ActiveSheet.Parent ' workbook of the active sheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Value = Application.Trim(ws.UsedRange.Value)
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Only Cells With Values**

```vb
Sub TrimAllWorksheets()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' or:
    'Set wb = ActiveSheet.Parent ' workbook of the active sheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, arg As Range
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rg = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error Goto 0
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            For Each arg In rg.Areas
                arg.Value = Application.Trim(arg.Value)
            Next arg
            Set rg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**Specific Worksheets**

```vb
Sub TrimSpecificWorksheets()
    
    Dim TrimSheets(): TrimSheets = Array("I", "B", "C")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' or:
    'Set wb = ActiveSheet.Parent ' workbook of the active sheet
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, arg As Range
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets(TrimSheets)
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rg = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error Goto 0
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            For Each arg In rg.Areas
                arg.Value = Application.Trim(arg.Value)
            Next arg
            Set rg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you ! I also have other worksheets in the actual real file. Is there anyway I could only specifically target worksheet I , B and C ?

Comment: I have corrected the code: `Set rg = Nothing` is necessary while `arg.Value` instead of `arg` is optional, a matter of being explicit when the expression `arg.Value = Application.Trim(arg.Value)` translates to something like: 1.) return the values of the range in an array (`arg.Value` on the right side of the expression), 2.) trim all values in the array (`Application.Trim(arg.Value)`) and 3.) write the trimmed values of the array back to the range.